# Trying to access a new activity by selecting RadioButton in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a radioGroup with 3 radioButtons. Once you select a radio button it should take you to another activity and access a specific fragment within that second activity. I have no compile or runtime errors. The issue: you can select radioButton but nothing happens. I am new to android studios and java. I would appreciate any help.  Most questions are using a button to access a new activity not a radio button.

```
package com.example.joseph.ex51_twoactivities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    //EditText etMessage;
    RadioButton profOne;
    RadioButton profTwo;
    RadioButton profThree;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       //etMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
       profOne = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdProf1);
       profTwo = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdProf2);
       profThree = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdProf3);
       if(profOne.isChecked()) {
           profOne.setOnClickListener(this);
       }
       if(profTwo.isChecked()) {
           profTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
       }
       if(profThree.isChecked()) {
           profThree.setOnClickListener(this);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I shouldn't have a conditional statement under the onCreate method.

Comment: why you cannot have *conditional statement under the onCreate method* ?

Comment: For it to go to the new activity, it will not work...i believe having a condition statement in the above code is insignificant.  To clarify I am not saying you can not use conditional statements period within the onCreate method, just in the above code.